# Target container is not a DOM element, firebase deploy

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

I just finished my app and I was trying to deploy it (I might be a bit burn which is probably why I might be doing a small mistake).

[image]

I'm getting this, instead of my web application.

In the firebase INIT
this are the options I set up:

? Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this directory? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices.

- Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys

=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? build

? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes

? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No

? File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? Yes

- Wrote build/index.html

Then I run: `npm run build`

finally `firebase deploy` and it should be done but it doesn't seem to be working.

Did I miss or did something wrong ?

**Files in firebase console**

[image]

**Full Image of what I see**

[image]

**Error I'm getting**

[image]

[image]

***Final Update***

For some reason my index.html file was override by the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.4/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      body { background: #ECEFF1; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87); font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #message { background: white; max-width: 360px; margin: 100px auto 16px; padding: 32px 24px; border-radius: 3px; }
      #message h2 { color: #ffa100; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 8px; }
      #message h1 { font-size: 22px; font-weight: 300; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); margin: 0 0 16px;}
      #message p { line-height: 140%; margin: 16px 0 24px; font-size: 14px; }
      #message a { display: block; text-align: center; background: #039be5; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; color: white; padding: 16px; border-radius: 4px; }
      #message, #message a { box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); }
      #load { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); text-align: center; font-size: 13px; }
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        body, #message { margin-top: 0; background: white; box-shadow: none; }
        body { border-top: 16px solid #ffa100; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
      <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!</p>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/">Open Hosting Documentation</a>
    </div>
    <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const loadEl = document.querySelector('#load');
        // // 
        // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
        //
        // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
        // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
        // firebase.firestore().doc('/foo/bar').get().then(() => { });
        // firebase.functions().httpsCallable('yourFunction')().then(() => { });
        // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
        // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
        // firebase.analytics(); // call to activate
        // firebase.analytics().logEvent('tutorial_completed');
        // firebase.performance(); // call to activate
        //
        // // 

        try {
          let app = firebase.app();
          let features = [
            'auth', 
            'database', 
            'firestore',
            'functions',
            'messaging', 
            'storage', 
            'analytics', 
            'remoteConfig',
            'performance',
          ].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
          loadEl.textContent = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
        } catch (e: any) {
          console.error(e);
          loadEl.textContent = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just changed that to what I had before and it worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Some Content"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
    
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Some Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see in firebase console in hosting route that files are there ? You should have release history table with all project versions uploads.

Comment: Yes I can see 116 files, I'll attach image

Comment: And when you click link above `.web.app` or `.firebaseapp.com` what it shows you ? Try to hard refresh page shift/ctrl + F5 thepends on system you use.

Comment: I already try refresh, hard refresh, erase all cache/cookies etc, this would be my third app idk why is doing this.

Comment: When you enter link you have an error in console about react. And `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`

Comment: Completely forgot to check my console jesus, How I can fix that error ? it doesn't tell me in which script/component is.

Comment: Delete or modify your question so it will fit to error from react you getting.

Comment: Done, I really do not know why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You should get more information about this DOM element when you run development mode on your computer.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` looks like there is TypeScript embedded in a script tag in `index.html`. `} catch (e: any) {` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: So for some reason both of my HTML files got replaced by some giberish of firebase instead of what it had before. Problem SOLVED. thanks guys